# ValueError: math domain error when calculating Negative IRR

Tags: python, math, scipy

I have the below reproducible case which gives me error:

```
return reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, map(lambda x: x[1] / math.pow(1 + i, x[0]),zip(dcfs, values)))
```

> ValueError: math domain error

This is already a very simplified case. If I invest $100 and only get $50 back after almost one year(0.99), which could happen in real world, say I deposit money on January 1st and get the money back on December 28th. the IRR should be -50%.

I can see there are two ways of fixing the below:

1. Change the dcfs to [0,1], then it will work
2. Change the initial guess to be -0.05

However, when I have a more complicated case with negative IRR, either of the above works (I cannot change all cashflows to be on exact year end and even I change initial guess to -0.05 it still breaks with the error). Can anyone help?

```
import math
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
from functools import reduce

dcfs = [0,0.99]
values = [-100,50]
initialGuess = 0.05

def npvFromIrr(i):
    return reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, map(lambda x: x[1] / math.pow(1 + i, x[0]),zip(dcfs, values)))

sol, info, ier, msg = fsolve(npvFromIrr, initialGuess, full_output=True)
print(sol)
```

Comment: The `ValueError: math domain error` is raised when you perform a mathematical function on a negative or zero number which cannot be computed. To solve this error, make sure you are using a valid number for the mathematical function you are using.

Comment: The error in your code is caused by the `-100` in `values = [-100,50]`. The code works well if you replace it with a positive number. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?
`

Comment: it's for calculating IRR, negative means outgoing cashflow and positive means incoming cashflow. negative number is not an issue as you can see if I change the dcf to [0,1] then it works. the problem is with fsolve, it should be able to find the answer -0.5 easily...

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you could convert the cash flow periods to days instead of years - (and adjust the initial guess if required)

```
dcfs = [_*365.25 for _ in dcfs]
initialGuess = -0.05/365.25

sol, info, ier, msg = fsolve(npvFromIrr, initialGuess, full_output=True)
```

This gives a value of array([-0.00191507]) - which you can convert back to an annual rate by

```
annual_rate = math.pow((1 + sol[0]), 365.35) - 1
# -0.5035836839765218
```

Alternatively, you can see if some of the other solvers within `scipy.optimize` can solve it without trying to raise a negative number to a real number